# Client certificat bug with Jelly beans

Tags: android, certificate, ssl

With Android, I use a TLS connexion with mutual authentification with a client certificate created with this code.

```
private static X509Certificate generateX509V1Certificate(KeyPair pair, SecureRandom sr)
{
  String dn="CN="+sUuid.toString();
  final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, -1);
  final Date startDate = new Date(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
  calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
  final Date expiryDate = new Date(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
  final BigInteger serialNumber =   
    BigInteger.valueOf(Math.abs(System.currentTimeMillis()));
  X509V1CertificateGenerator certGen = new X509V1CertificateGenerator();
  X500Principal dnName = new X500Principal(dn);
  certGen.setSerialNumber(serialNumber);
  certGen.setIssuerDN(dnName);
  certGen.setNotBefore(startDate);
  certGen.setNotAfter(expiryDate);
  certGen.setSubjectDN(dnName); // note: same as issuer
  certGen.setPublicKey(pair.getPublic());
  certGen.setSignatureAlgorithm("SHA256WithRSAEncryption");
  if (VERSION.SDK_INT<VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    return certGen.generateX509Certificate(pair.getPrivate(), "BC");
  else
    return  certGen.generate(pair.getPrivate(), sr);
}
```

The key pair algorithm is "RSA".
The cipher algorithm is "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding".

It's work fine before Jelly Bean version.

With Jelly bean, I receive an error when I invoke

```
socket.getSession().getPeerCertificates()
```

The process was killed with in the log :

```
E/NativeCrypto(1133): error:140C10F7:SSL routines:SSL_SET_PKEY:unknown certificate type
A/libc(1133): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 1233 (AsyncTask #1)
```

I have no idea how I can resolve this bug.

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 2):

Dump the generated certificate to a file and try to parse it OpenSSL 1.0. That is the same code that Android uses to parse certificates, so it should help you find the error. Maybe they simply don't support v1 certificates anymore, you could try generating a v3 one.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this issue and one more with following error:
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x3f80005c (code=1), thread 11709 (FinalizerDaemon)

They started happening at random when I upgraded to 4.1.1 on Galaxy S3 on an application that uses client SSL authentication by consuming keys from the KeyChain API.

It worked fine on 4.0.4 (fortunatelly I managed to downgrade).

I'm not 100% sure but 4.1.1 seems to have quite a few bugs related to the SSL - check this one: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35141
and also this one: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34577 (might not be that relevant for the current case)
Also in this forum post: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/Lj2iHX4prds there is a mention about SEGFAULT when doing GC on the PrivateKey object returned from the KeyChain API.

So as an final advise - stay on 4.0.4 as long as possible or go to 4.1.2 - there seems to be some bug fixes.

Also I can confirm that the two issues that I had are not present on the 4.1.2 emulator. There is no 4.1.2 image for Galaxy S3 so I'm not able to confirm them as fixed for a real device (don't have another one).

Hope that heps.